# Table as field in model

Tags: django, orm, model

I have such models:

```py
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey('Schedule', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Schedule(models.Model):
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    shift_start = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    shift_end = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

Each department have a schedule - some `[post_name, shift_start, shift_end]` lines for each post. If use `ForeignKey` there will be only one line instead of a list. Is it possible to create some `Schedule` tables and link each with certain `Department`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key defines a 1 to N relationship between your models. If I understood right you would like 1 department to have N schedules. To achieve this each schedule should have a foreign key defining which department it belongs to.

So you should use `ForeignKey` for that, but put it in your `Schedule` model.

Here is how it should look:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Schedule(models.Model):
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    shift_start = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    shift_end = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='schedules')
```

Then after you've created a department and a couple of schedules for that department you can access them like so:
(lets assume the created department primary key is 1)

```
Department.objects.get(pk=1).schedules.all()
```